# Clarification on the 6-Month Yield Point on the US Treasury Yield Curve

Tags: bonds, treasury, yield-curve

Can the 6-month yield point on the US Treasury Yield Curve represent yields from securities originally issued with longer maturities (e.g., 1 year) but now have only 6 months left until maturity?

..*Or* does it exclusively reflect yields from securities issued with a 6-month maturity?

Put differently, is 30-year bonds maturing in 6 months plotted at the 6-month point on the x-axis, alongside newly issued 6-month bonds.

Comment: If they pay the same amount on the same date, what difference would remain between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [US Treasury](https://home.treasury.gov/policy-issues/financing-the-government/interest-rate-statistics):

> This par yield curve, which relates the par yield on a security to its time to maturity, is based on the closing market bid prices on the **most recently auctioned Treasury securities in the over-the-counter market**. The par yields are derived from input market prices, which are indicative quotations obtained by the Federal Reserve Bank of New York at approximately 3:30 PM each business day.

However, the 6-month node is not based strictly on 6-month bills, or bills/notes/bonds with 6 months to maturity, but a combination of yields for *all* bonds, since it uses a sophisticated interpolation/fitting algorithm to fit the yield curve to all points.

The yield that is reported is the yield that you should *expect* to get from any US bond that has exactly 6 months to maturity. However, since bonds are issues only once a month, it's not common to find bonds that represent exact points on the yield curve.