# Is the yield of a 30-year bond, issued 29 years ago and maturing in 1 year, equivalent to that of a 1-year bond maturing on the same date?

Tags: bonds, government-bonds, yield, fixed-income

The question assumes both bonds are US Treasury bonds.

I'm seeking clarity on whether the difference in original issuance date and remaining time to maturity impacts yield parity between these bonds.

Any insights on this would be valuable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clarification on the 6-Month Yield Point on the US Treasury Yield Curve](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/161450/clarification-on-the-6-month-yield-point-on-the-us-treasury-yield-curve)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, since there is no credit risk, you should expect to get the same yield as a newly issued 1-year bill and a 30-year bond with 1 year remaining.

In practice, however, there is a *liquidity premium* since there is more competition for newly issued bonds than bonds that someone already holds, so you might get *slightly less* yield for an existing bond (called "off-the-run") than a newly issued bond (called "on-the-run"). However the difference should not be be material, otherwise there would be an arbitrage possibility.

There *might* also be slight differences in yield if the coupons are significantly different, since, depending on the cash flow strategy, one might be willing to pay more for a higher coupon bond since they get at least some cash flow earlier.  But the difference should be relatively small here as well.

Comment: While not hugely significant to individual investors cashflow management is integral to  the business models of, for example, pension funds  and distributing ETFs so buying the right coupon bearing bond is essential for them. +1

Comment: Is it an established fact that off the run bonds trade at a lower yield than on the run bonds?  I would expect the liquidity premium to go in the other direction, with investors less willing to hold the less liquid bonds.  You would expect that to drive prices down and therefore yields up.

Comment: @Nobody _slightly_ lower sometimes. I believe the premium is more due to liquidity, since treasury bonds are easier to get directly, there's more competition, and you get more favorable prices. OTC tend to have higher bid/ask spreads. In other words, I don't think it's a _preference_ that buyers want more liquid bonds, just that they get better prices in more liquid markets.

Comment: Hmm, weird.  I would expect more competition to lead to less favorable prices, in effect creating a seller's market.  Likewise, I would expect buyers faced with high spreads to be less willing to pay (i.e., they would demand higher yields), since they know that they are likely to take a haircut when and if they sell. FYI, if you google "liquidity premium", the capsule summary is: "Liquidity premium is the extra yield built into the returns on an asset if it cannot be cashed in easily or quickly," which suggests that all else being equal, yield is normally higher on less liquid securities.

Comment: Yes I suppose that's true as well - if you buy a less liquid security you could expect to have more trouble selling, and would want to buy it cheaper to compensate. Either way, it is common for off-the-run bonds to have slightly lower yields.